# Redis accessibility from multiple machines for eg. x.x.2.2 and x.x.2.5

Tags: java, unix, redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

Redis storage I've installed on server x.x.2.2 and I've another load balanced server x.x.2.5. Can redis be accessed by both the machines ?

Comment: This seems to be a networking question. As long as you can get a socket open inwards towards the server on the listening port: you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access it.

If you're using java, then I would suggest using Jedis. It's easy to setup. https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki